# Get value from lxml.etree._Element

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

Having the following:

```
from lxml import html
import io
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.HTMLParser() 
doc   = etree.parse(io.FileIO("index.html"), parser)
i=1

total = []

aa = doc.xpath(".//body/table[10]")
for x in aa:
    for j in x:
        for k in j:
            print type(k) #output is <type 'lxml.etree._Element'>
            print k.text
```

Part of html file:

http://pastebin.com/2eftj9qL

This will display:

```
/Request_number_1
15
0
100.00%
1035 ms
923 ms
1407 ms
None


/Request_number_2
15
0
100.00%
966 ms
857 ms
1613 ms
None
```

How can I iterate trough this lxml element? I want to retrieve the first value expressed in milliseconds (ex. average_time_array = [1035 ms, 966ms])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using this xpath expression? `.//body/table[1]/tr/td[5]`

```
average_time_array = [td.text for td in doc.xpath(".//body/table[10]/tr/td[5]")]
print average_time_array
```